# IHow to apply the density of $C_0^1(\Omega)$ in $W_0^{1,1}(\Omega)$ to derive the identity in the following?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm reading the book by Gilbarg and Trudinger.

In Lemma 7.14, the authors proved that if $u \in C_0^1(\Omega)$, then 
$$u(x)=\frac{1}{nw_n}\int_{\Omega}\frac{(x_i-y_i)D_iu(y)}{|x-y|^n}dy.$$
Then right after this the authors claim that if $u \in W_0^{1,1}(\Omega)$, then using the fact that $C_0^1(\Omega)$ is dense in $W_0^{1,1}(\Omega)$, one can obtain 
$$u(x)=\frac{1}{nw_n}\int_{\Omega}\frac{(x_i-y_i)D_iu(y)}{|x-y|^n}dy \quad a.e. $$

I can't see why here, because $\frac{(x_i-y_i)}{|x-y|^n}$ is singular.

Can anyone give me some ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not singular. Let $x=0$. Then you have a weight $-\frac{y_i}{\lvert y\rvert^n}$ which in polar coordinates reads $\frac{\text{some bounded function}}{r^{n-1}}$. (I assume that $\Omega$ is bounded here)

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro, I see. If the kernel is bounded, then the argument is true for sure. If the kernel is not bunded, even if it's integrable, I still don't know how to justify the argument in the book.

Comment: You are right that it is not trivial. This material: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_potential might prove useful to you. (With $\alpha=1$)

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro, thank you very much! It's very useful!

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro, so the argument goes like this. If $u_k=I_{\alpha}(Du_k)$ and $u_k \rightarrow u$ in $W_0^{1,1}(\Omega)$, then by the embedding property of $I_{\alpha}$, $I_{\alpha}(Du_k) \rightarrow I_{\alpha}(Du)$ in $L^1(\Omega)$. Also $u_k \rightarrow u$ in $L^1$, then up to a subsequence, both $u_k \rightarrow u$ and $I_{\alpha}(Du_k) \rightarrow I_{\alpha}(Du)$ almost everywhere. Hence $u=I_{\alpha}(Du) \quad a.e.$. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue as follows. Assume that $n\ge 2$ and let 
$$
T_i f (x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y)\frac{x_i-y_i}{\lvert x-y\rvert^{n}}\chi_\Omega(y)\, dy.$$
Here $\chi_\Omega(y)$ is $1$ if $y\in \Omega$ and $0$ otherwise. The kernel of this operator can be estimated in absolute value by the kernel of the Riesz potential:
$$
\left\lvert \frac{x_i-y_i}{\lvert x-y\rvert^{n}} \right\rvert\le C\frac1{\lvert x-y\rvert^{n-1}}.$$
It is a consequence of this that $T_i$ is continuous from $L^1(\Omega)$ to $L^{\frac n{n-1}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, because 
$$
\left\lVert T_if\right\rVert_{L^\frac{n}{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le C_1\left\lVert I_1(\lvert f\rvert\chi_\Omega)\right\rVert_{L^\frac{n}{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le C_2\lVert f\rVert_{L^1(\Omega)}, $$
the second inequality being [Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev's one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_potential)$^{[1]}$.

In the problem at hand, if $u\in W^{1,1}_0(\Omega)$ we can approximate it with a sequence $u_k\in C^1_0(\Omega)$ in such a way that 
$$u_k\to u\qquad \text{in }W^{1,1}(\Omega).$$
We have that $u_k=T_i \left(\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_i}\right)$ for all $k$. Here the left hand side is $L^1$ convergent to $u$ and the right hand side is $L^{\frac n{n-1}}$ convergent to $T_i\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right)$. Therefore the limits must be equal almost everywhere, because both modes of convergence imply the pointwise convergence of a subsequence at almost all points.

---

$[1]$ If $\Omega$ is bounded, one might probably avoid using this inequality and resort to the conceptually simpler [Young's inequality for convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality#Young.27s_inequality_for_convolutions) with $p=1$ and $r=q\in \left[1, \frac{n}{n-1}\right)$ (notations taken from Wikipedia's page). This works in dimension $1$ too. If needed I can fill in the details.